# Symfony upgrade 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: symfony, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my old symfony app to sf 2.7 by adding version to composer.json and executing :

```
composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

I use PHP 7.2. I have this error :

```
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

   Problem 1
        - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.50
        ...
        - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.10
        - Installation request for nelmio/api-doc-bundle (locked at 2.13.3, required as ~2.7) -> satisfiable by nelmio/api-doc-bundle[2.13.3].
        - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.9
        ...
        - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.1
        - don't install symfony/asset v3.4.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
        - don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0|remove symfony/asset v3.4.23
        - don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0|don't install symfony/asset v3.4.23
        - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v
    2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31,
     v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.
    48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9].
        - Installation request for symfony/asset (locked at v3.4.23) -> satisfiable by symfony/asset[v3.4.23].
```

At last, i'd like to upgrade to 2.8

Could anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you corrected your code before running composer update? Did you read the [official Symfony upgrade lineguides](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md)? Also if you need PHP 7.2 you need to use Symfony 4 but there are too many differences and maybe you should consider to rewrite your app from a fresh 4.2 installation.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are upgrading Symfony/symfony with the related dependencies , that means that composer will adpated all dependencies that are required to the Symfony/symfony only , but the other dependencies in your require and require-dev will not be updated .

But the error , you got , means that in your composer.json , you have in the require section the dependencie:

```
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle" : "2.13.3"
  .
  .
  .
"symfony/symfony" : "2.7"
```

> So , you want to migrate to symfony version 2.7 while the
>   nelmio/api-doc-bundle have conflict with this version ([look this link
>   here in packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/nelmio/api-doc-bundle#2.13.3) )

So here is the best solution to manage your dependencies version :

1. delete the compoer.lock
2. open your composer.json add modify the version of symfony/symfony like

   "symfony/symfony" : "2.8.*"
3. list all you require and require-dev  and check every dependencie in https://packagist.org to see what is required and what are conflict with the actual version .
4. it's necessary to use versions constraint , so that based on the composer version you have , check the offical documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)

   Hope this help you